# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 with api

Tags: java, android

```
class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //creating request handler object
        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

        //creating request parameters
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("mobile", mobile);
        params.put("password", password);

        //returning the response
        return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_REGISTER, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try {

            //converting response to json object
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

            //int a= obj.getInt("success");
            int b=obj.getInt("success");
            //if no error in response
            if ( b==1) {
                Snackbar.make(parent_view, obj.getString("alert"), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //starting the OTP activity
                signintxt.setText("OTP");
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frmframelayout, new fragment_reg_otp(), "reg_otp").addToBackStack("reg_otp").commit();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(parent_view, obj.getString("alert"), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//executing the async task
RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
ru.execute();
```

Getting the error

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
    at fragment_signup$1RegisterUser.onPostExecute(fragment_signup.java:132)
    at .fragment_signup$1RegisterUser.onPostExecute(fragment_signup.java:107)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:714)
```

I am getting this error when I press the submit button after filling all the details to post data to the server into my database but it shows me above error in run tab.

I have api link and I am using retrofit, request handler. I am not understanding this error.

Comment: Can you add your `requestHandler` code?

Comment: Md.Asaduzzaman yes i have added that

Answer (score 1):

This clearly indicates that the response you're getting from the API is not a valid JSON object. Try to log the String s variable in the onPostExecute method to get the exact output you're getting from the API. Mostly happens when the API returns a 500 error